# Deploy an Angular 8 application to IIS

Tags: angular, iis

I have an Angular 8 application with a separate class library for data retrieval (DAL). I use controllers to retrieve the data. I can't figure out how to deploy or publish it to IIS. It creates a publish folder with a ton of files and the Clientapp folder that houses the index.html/angular files. I tried adding rewrite to the web.config and it still doesn't seem to work. I'm right clicking on the project and select publish, publish to local file system, and then copy the files/folders to the server/IIS. If I copy the ClientApp files the application comes up but there's no data and the services fail.

Comment: This blog might useful in your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304626/how-to-deploy-angular-cli-app-on-iis

Comment: you could use `ng build` command to build an application for that first enter to the folder using command prompt and run this command. it will create a dist folder under your project folder. open iis and point the dist folder as the folder path when you add site.

Comment: could you share which feature of iis you installed?

Comment: Hi Dennis, maybe this article will help https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-deploy-angular-app-to-an-iis-web-server-complete-setup-337997486423